# How to delete a ListView Item by a function in UserControl Template?

Tags: c#, listview, user-controls, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I am Developing windows 10 Universal app with c#.
I have a UserControl that is the MyListview item template. Listview will Bind the data. In userControl,there is a button for Delete the usercontrol DependencyProperty Content(contain string Text, Name and int Id ).

Listview show the text of object and the button for remove it.

Now how can remove that item from my List by click on remove Button?

**Update**

my Data class:

```
class Data
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

my usercontrol.cs :

```
public Data Content
{
     get { return (Data)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
     set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Content.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
 public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(Data), typeof(MyUserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

usercontrol xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding Content.Text, ElementName=textBlock}" />
    <Button Click="Remove_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

my list implementing:

```
<Page.Resources>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewTemplate">
          <local:MyUserControl1 Content="{Binding}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
   <ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewTemplate}" />
</Grid>
```

and in the code behinde the Page I use an `ObservableCollection<Data> items = new ObservableCollection<Data>();`to set `Listview.ItemsSource` to it.

The main Problem is How to remove that item from the `items` in MyUsercontrol1

Comment: So you don't how to implement Remove_Click, do you?

Comment: @MichałKomorowski  yes, i want press remove button and the item remove from the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote about binding so I'm assuming that in your XAML there is a following code or similar:

```
<ListView ItemSource = "{Bind SomeCollection"} ... />
```

If I'm right there is no much to do. If `SomeCollection` is of type `ObservableCollection<T>` it is enough to remove an item from `SomeCollection` and UI will be refreshed ''automatically''. To sum up:

1. Declare `SomeCollection` as `ObservableCollection<T>`.
2. In a command that is executed when *Delete* button is clicked (or in an event handler) simply call  `ObservableCollection<T>.Remove`.

**UPDATE**

This code is not elegant but shows an idea. Firstly we need to modify `Data` class:

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Action<Data> OnRemoveCallback { get; set; }

    public void OnRemove()
    {
        OnRemoveCallback(this);
    }
}
```

`OnRemoveCallback` will be used to inform `ListView` that a given data element should be removed. `Remove_click` handler  in `MyUserControl` simply executes `OnRemove`:

```
private void Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Content.OnRemove();
}
```

Finally, in the code behind of your `Page` we have to define a logic that will be responsible for actual removing data items from the list:

```
public void Remove(Data d)
{
    ((ObservableCollection<Data>) ListView.ItemsSource).Remove(d);
}
```

...

```
ListView.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Data>()
{
    new Data() {Id = 1, Text = "1", OnRemoveCallback = Remove},
    new Data() {Id = 2, Text = "2", OnRemoveCallback = Remove}
};
```

Now your Page will be informed whenever *Delete* button is pressed and will do a job.

As I said it is not a perfect solution. Personally, I'll use MVVM pattern. Thanks do that XAML and C# will be seperated.

Comment: I'm using the ObservableCollection<T>  but the main problem is how to delete it from the MyUserControle.

Comment: @AliMalek You need to remove the data item from the collection, not the UserControl itself. If you delete the item, the UserControl will be removed by the list.

Comment: But it is being removed from the ObservableCollection<Data> collection. Now, I do not understand what you want to achieve.